Dockers adds encoded characters
I have a filed called ssh_key.txt and the content of that file is: my_private_key
In my Dockerfile I have this instruction:
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ssh_key \
  cat /run/secrets/ssh_key > /home/${USER_NAME}/.ssh/git_key

When I build this image:
docker build --secret id=ssh_key,src=ssh_key.txt -t my_image.

And run the image, when I cd into the .ssh directory and run:
cat git_key
Weirdly the content is:
"��my_private_key"

I don't understand where the �� is coming from, does anyone know I could be doing wrong?

It's 2 bytes that are sometimes included in UTF-8 files, called the byte order mark. If they're causing you issues, you can edit the file and save it as UTF-8 without BOM. Notepad in Windows has the option to save it without BOM and many other editors do too.

Are you expecting to see your ssh private key; in plain text; readily accessible like that to anyone who has a copy of the image?

@DavidMaze Yes pretty much, i dont want to have to go into the file to edit and remove the characters

This shows a way to remove the BOM using sed.
